# Where should I report a bug and apply the fix?

Tags: debian, bug-reporting, sane

I've identified a bug in XSane and have a four-line fix for it. I'm a little confused as to where I should go to have this fix incorporated... Should I submit a bug report to Ubuntu, Debian, XSane, or all three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSane is in universe and from looking at it it looks like we import this package from Debian. However it seems the author [does not read](http://www.xsane.org/xsane-mailinglist.html) that list.

In this case I would file the bug and post to the [XSane mailing list](http://www.sane-project.org/mailing-lists.html) (I can't seem to find a bug tracker for XSane) and then file a bug in the Debian BTS pointing to the fix.

If the XSane guys take your fix then you're basically done, but having the bug report in the BTS would be a way for the maintainer to see that there's a new fix going upstream that he might be interested in.

Then at some point we get the version in Debian. You can also file a bug in Launchpad but it's probably not needed.

In your case you mention that the project hasn't made a release in a year, in that case filing a bug in Debian is the appropriate thing to do and attach your patch.

Comment: That's the SANE mailing list, which the XSane author [does not read](http://www.xsane.org/xsane-mailinglist.html) at present. I guess I email him direct instead. There's not been a release in a year though - is there benefit in getting a patch in at the Debian or Ubuntu level, or does that create too much work?

Comment: Good info, I've updated my answer.

Comment: bug reporting is here with a link to the bug tracker... http://www.sane-project.org/bugs.html

Comment: @fossfreedom Cool, I'd assumed that SANE wouldn't be interested in XSane issues.